# Template class not looping with str_replace

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, str-replace

Well i have this set of codes

```
<?php
include "includes/config.php";
class template{
    var $page;
    var $built;
    public $block = array();

    function _start($tpl){
        $this->page = $tpl;
    }

    function set_array($data){
        $this->block[] = $data;
    }

    function _show(){
        foreach($this->block as $k => $v){
            foreach($v as $k1 => $v1){
                //echo $k1."<br />";
                //echo $v1."<br />";
                $this->page = str_replace("{".$k1."}", $v1, $this->page);
            }
        }
        echo $this->page;
    }
}

$template = new template();

$file = "<html>
<body>
<p>{CAT}</p>
<p>{SUBCAT}</p>
</body>
</html>";

$template->_start($file);

// Category Query
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($cat)){

$template->set_array(array("CAT" => $row1['title']));

// Sub Category Query
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($subcat)){

$template->set_array(array("SUBCAT" => $row2['title']));

}
}

$template->_show();

?>
```

Now, when i echo $k1 or $v1 they display the keys and values in the correct order like

CAT1
SUBCAT1.1
SUBCAT1.2
CAT2
SUBCAT2.1
SUBCAT2.2

but when it goes through the str_replace its only displays the CAT1 and SUBCAT1.2 what going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the variable $page inside the foreach() loop; either you make it an array or you append to the variable. Could be:

```
function _show(){
       $this->page = '';
        foreach($this->block as $k => $v){
            foreach($v as $k1 => $v1){
                $this->page .= str_replace("{".$k1."}", $v1, $this->page); //appending every time onto the previous. As you were doing:
                // $this->page =str_replace("{".$k1."}", $v1, $this->page);
                // here you were overwriting $this->page at every passage of the loop
            }
        }
        echo $this->page;
    }
```

Comment: No concating didn't do any good instead it went over and looped several times.

Comment: I realized I had a little mistake in my code, I corrected it. Anyway, what's the purpose of looping if you don't want a loop? Maybe I dind't understand what you needed.

Comment: Basically its a template engine i have categories and subcategories in the database what i want is i assign {CAT} and {SUBCAT} in an html file and it displays the categories and subcategories in the right order which is possible inside a nested while loop so i made a new array and added all the values in the right order but now in the str_replace part it overwrites all the values like you said earlier how do i overcome this problem?

Comment: Don't know how to explain that, but 2 solutions: 1) build another array: `$new_array[] = str_replace("{".$k1."}", $v1, $this->page)` or 2) you go in append; I'll go for the latter, it's easier.

Comment: Well i tried making a new array and it worked a bit but i got to know one thing well the foreach is also repeating all the keys tags i made in the html string like 

CAT1
{SUBCAT}
{CAT}
SUBCAT1.1
{CAT}
SUBCAT1.2
CAT2
{SUBCAT}
{CAT}
SUBCAT2.1
{CAT}
SUBCAT2.2

Now why is that so? can't it peacefully display everything in the right order and i surly don't want to switch to Smarty and others.